# Digital PLL loses lock every time mesage crosses zero

Tags: synchronization, pll

I think my digital PLL is almost ready, but I've encountered this problem and I don't know what might be causing it, so I'd appreciate if you could help.

I'm using the DPLL in a Costas loop. It seems to work fine but whenever the message crosses zero, lock is lost. After that, it ends up locking again. You can see here:

[image]

Input to the Costas loop is:
$$
x(t) = m(t)cos(2\pi f_ct+\theta_{in})
$$
$$
m(t) = cos(2\pi f_mt)
$$
where $f_m << f_c$

Not sure if this is a known phenomenom (it probably is) but I haven't been able to find anything related. It'd be nice if you could point out what's going on and/or how to fix the temporary loss of lock?

One way I've managed to get it "working" consisted of squaring the message signal (although phase error rises a bit when message goes near zero), but I don't wish to square it so that wouldn't be of use to me.

This is the Costas loop I'm implementing for this test:

[image: costas loop]

Comment: You need to show more detail.  Can you show your Costas loop, and describe what constitutes a symbol?  It looks like your "Costas" loop is locking to the phase of $x(t)$ independent of the message.

Comment: I edited the original post to show the Costas loop (the pic at the bottom). As for the symbols, well, for this test I'm simply generating $m(t)$ as described in my main post, once this is successful, I'd move on to BPSK and pulse shaping. Not too sure if this solves your question; let me know if it doesn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are having trouble because that's not a Costas loop.  A Costas loop uses demodulated data in some form to change the phase that's expected from the signal.

You're just taking the I/Q demodulated signal and applying it to the atan2 function; that makes a sort of linearized extended phase detector, but without determining that the phase *should have* flipped by 180 degrees, your loop is naturally trying to follow the phase that's actually coming in.

You could make your loop into a simple Costas loop by changing the atan2 function into a multiply, and following it by a proper loop filter.

Comment: It did work! Changing atan2 by a multiplier and adding a loop filter, it's working now! Thank you very much. When you say it's a simple Costas loop, it's because it could be improved somehow? Also, I'd like to know some more info about it: as far as I understand by your reply, if I wanted to use atan2 I'd need some sort of decision-directed method?

Comment: I tend to conflate "Costas loop" with "decision directed" loop.  I'm not sure what's considered to be the dividing line these days.  I think the improvements I had in the back of my mind would push it more into decision-directed territory.

Comment: And yes, if you wanted to use an atan2 function in there you'd want a decision-directed loop.  But you'd want to ask yourself why you were doing it -- you want your phase error to be small, and that implies that the approximation $\theta \simeq \sin \theta$ holds -- so why bother with atan2?

Comment: Oh, I see. So as long as I'm sure that the initial $\theta_{in}-\theta$ is small enough so that $sin(2\theta_{in} - 2\theta)\simeq2\theta_{in} - 2\theta$, I can use the simple Costas loop you proposed, right? And if I wanted to address a larger $\theta_{in}-\theta$, I'd need to consider implementing a decision-directed loop. At least that's what I'm seeing in my simulations, it works fine for $\theta_{in}-\theta$ not bigger than $\pi/2$

Comment: In general a PLL is assumed to work on a data *stream*, and it is acceptable for it to take some time to lock.  Just a plain multiplier will always lock, at least if there's noise to kick it out of the unstable equilibrium when the phase difference is equal to $\pi$.  If you need to acquire the phase of a packet or something then you need a different synchronization technique.

Comment: I'm working on data stream and that makes me wonder if mine contains some sort of mistake since it doesn't always lock, only for a certain range of phase difference (if it's out of $(−\pi/2,\pi/2)$, it won't lock) [link](https://imgur.com/X8sqggh)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your error jumps to -$\pi$ and then to $\pi$

I think you need to unwrap your phase. Let me explain with an example

Say that the output of atan2 block is $\pi - 0.001$ and then the phase difference increases by 0.002 rad, the outuput of the atan 2 block should then be $\pi$ + 0.001, however the atan2 output is limited to ±$\pi$. Therefore the output will be -$\pi$ + 0.001 rad instead of $\pi$ + 0.001. It is up to you to manage these discontinuties with an unwrap function.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html

Please note however, that for some PLLs (like in power systems), we do not unwrap the phase, we simply switch to FLL mode (frequency-locked-loop) when the frequency difference is too great. Once, the frequency is locked, we switch to PLL mode. In this implementation we do not need to unwrap the phase.